# Determine if injective or surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I need to work out if the following function is surjective or injective. I'm unsure as I've just started learning it.

$$h: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb  N,\quad h(x) = x^2  + 10$$

Comment: Is there a number $x \in N$ with $h(x) = 1$? What's that say about surjectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injective means that if $h(x) = h(y)$, then $x=y$.

Surjective means that $\forall z \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists x \in \mathbb{N}$, $z = f(x)$.

Let's try to work out if $h$ is surjective.
$\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$, $x^2 \geq 0$ so $h(x) \geq 10$. But $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and we have just proven that it can't have an antecedent since $0<10$. So h isn't surjective.

Now, injectivity. Let's take $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $h(x) = h(y)$. So we have $x^2+10 = y^2+10$, so $x^2 = y^2$. As we work in $\mathbb{N}$, $x$ and $y$ must be positive integers so $x=y$. We have proven injectivity for $h$.

Answer (score 2):

A function f(x) is injective if and only if 
 f(x)=f(y) implies x=y. 
 This is the case here because $x^2+10$ is an increasing function 
 in the natural numbers. 
 If $x_1 < x_2$ , we have $x_1^2 + 10 < x_2^2+10$. Analogue, you show that
 $x_2 < x_1$ leads to different values. So $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$

A function f(x) is surjective if and only if for every y 
 there exists an x with f(x)=y.
 This is not the case here because $h(x) = x^2+10 = 12$  has no
 natural solution.